# Understanding Coherence Near Cache + Extend/.NET

Tags: oracle-coherence

I'm new to Coherence. Per my understanding, it's possible for a Java app to run in the same JVM as a Coherence Near Cache (i.e. its *Local Front-Cache*) -- where doing a Get of a cached object can retrieve a **live** object (not a deserialized *copy* of the object).

While this is super efficient, a potential gotcha is that app thread 2 can have a reference to the same object; and see changes to the object made by thread 1 before thread 1 calls Put.

My question is : is this scenario possible when using `Extend`/.NET?  I'm thinking not, because even with the Near Cache running on the same server as the .NET app, TCP/IP is involved -- thus cached objects are copied/serialized/deserialized.  Is this true? Any insights are appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I can answer my own question; in case this helps anyone else...

I've found that even with Coherence*Extend/C#, the Near Cache runs in-process with the C# client app - where Gets of objects stored in Near Cache will be *live* objects (not deserialized copies of the object).